# why we do not inherit system.object explicitly

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

why we do not inherit system.object explicitly?

as we know base class of .net is system.object. Can somebody tell me at which point we inherit this class.

Comment: You don't need to. This is implicitly done by the language itself.

Comment: basically, doing so is equivalent to `string a = "hello world".ToString()`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class MyClass //:Object
{
}
```

The commented bit is done automatically. It is done for us because writing it every time is a waste of effort.

Answer (score 3):

The base class is set by the compiler automatically if none is specified. The compiler changes your code in many ways, for example, when you deal with auto-properties by automatically creating the backing field.